# projectRaster consuming too much memory

Tags: r, out-of-memory, rstudio, r-raster

I'm doing some spatial stuff in R and out of the blue some of my code will no longer work on a computer that I've been using for years, specifically because it's "running out of memory."

```
## Raster going in
xx <- raster(fatNames[[i]])
xx
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5160, 14436, 74489760  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -172.3, -52, 23.5, 66.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : D:\Dropbox\wintor_aux\Results\myluFatReq_100_2_fat.inf.tif 
names       : myluFatReq_100_2_fat.inf 
values      : 0.1831425, 3.449095  (min, max)

## transform
x.rast <- projectRaster(xx,crs = CRS("+init=epsg:2955"))
```

Error: can not adequate vector of 4.2Gb.

Now I know this is a decent sized raster (Input raster size: 75.5 MB) however the machine has 32Gb of RAM, no other programs are running and I still swamp the memory. I've done things like this hundreds of times over the years and to the best of my knowledge nothing on the machine has changed since I did this last about a month ago.

I've tried restarting the session, restarting the computer and have googled around a bit but I still haven't had any luck in trying to trace down the issues. When I try the same code block on a machine with 1/2 the RAM I'm able to run it no problem (using ~ 8Gb ram max). Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can chase this down?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.6-7         rgdal_1.3-3          sp_1.3-1             sf_0.6-3            
[5] RevoUtils_11.0.1     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18    lattice_0.20-35 class_7.3-14    grid_3.5.1      spData_0.2.9.0 
 [6] DBI_1.0.0       magrittr_1.5    e1071_1.7-0     units_0.6-0     tools_3.5.1    
[11] yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.5.1  classInt_0.2-3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first update the raster package to its current (CRAN) version. That might fix this. If not, this is probably a corner-case that you should be able to work-around by setting the memory parameters to a lower value. In the current version you could do `rasterOptions(memfrac=.3)`. In the current and older versions you may try `rasterOptions(maxmemory=1e+08)`

By the way, your transformation to `+proj=utm +zone=11` (please do not use espg codes in examples) seems rather questionable given that the input data has a longitude span of (172.3 - 52) = 120 degrees --- UTM is valid for a span of about 6 degrees.

Comment: The modifications to the `rasterOptions` was the real winner, even with the most up to-date package the default was still causing problems for whatever reason. Also thanks for pointing out the projection issue, luckily these are just for figures as the standard WGS84 deemed "too boxy" by some of the collaborators.

Comment: what is the best way to save the modified `rasterOptions` so it doesn't need to be updated with every new session?