# projectRaster consuming a lot of memory

Tags: geospatial, r-raster

This is a different question than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493477/projectraster-consuming-too-much-memory). I wish to transpose a [raster](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/south-korea-high-resolution-population-density-maps-demographic-estimates) (`population_kor_2018-10-01_geotiff.zip`) from CRS WGS84 to CRS 5179. In the process, the file size is multiplied by 65, which seems excessive, makes me think I may be doing something wrong and is also probably too large for the next steps I need to perform. I have modeled the `crs` parameter of `projectRaster` after this [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111226/how-to-assign-crs-to-rasterlayer-in-r#comment416020_111227).

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

r <- raster("population_kor_2018-10-01.tif")
crs(r) #+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
r <- projectRaster(r, crs=CRS('+init=EPSG:5179'), filename="r", overwrite=T)
```

Input file `population_kor_2018-10-01.tif` takes 28 Mb whereas ouput file `r.gri` takes 1.8 Gb. Although I am rather new at this, I don't understand how a coordinate transformation could have such a multiplicative effect. Am I doing something wrong and if not is there another less memory-intensive way? The raster is just an input for me, which I ultimately need to transform into polygons.

Comment: See `writeRaster` for options. You can use a different file format (e.g. tif), datatype (the input is perhaps an integer, you are writing double precision float), and with tif you can also use compression

Comment: @RobertHijmans The raster contains population count figures. `dataType(raster("population_kor_2018-10-01.tif"))` returns "FLT8S".

Comment: Then it is probably compressed